# Setting observable object to NULL == CRASH

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, radgridview

I have a List bound to a (Telerik) GridView. The selected item is a separate variable of type T which is assigned the object of the selected row in the GridView when the user clicks on a row. **T is derived from ObservableObject**. This means I am using **MVVM Light Toolkit**.

I need to deselect the row from my ViewModel in certain situations. On the GridView control this works, if the selected item is set to NULL in the ViewModel. Whenever I do this, MVVM reports a crash (NPE). I debugged it and saw that it is failing in ObservableObject.cs. It calls a method

```
    protected bool Set<T>(
        Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression,
        ref T field,
        T newValue)
```

and crashes one line before return when calling `RaisePropertyChanged(propertyExpression)`

I don't know if this is working as designed or not. My problem is, that I need to set the selected Object to NULL in the ViewModel to deselect a row of my GridView in the View. **I CANNOT use CodeBehind for the deselection**!

Code I have:

```
    public ObservableCollection<ContractTypeDto> ContractTypes { get; private set; }

    public ContractTypeDto SelectedContractType
    {
        get { return _selectedContractType; }
        set
        {
            Set(() => SelectedContractType, ref _selectedContractType, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedContractType);
        }
    }
```

When you click on a row in the grid it opens a new UserControl containing lots of details of this record. This control has its own ViewModel. I store the calling view Model (where the selected item is stored). When the page (control) is closed (destroyed) I have to deselect the row in the grid. I call a method like so:

```
    protected void DeselectCallersSelectedItem()
    {
        if (CallingObject == typeof(ContractTypeListViewModel))
        {
            var vm = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ContractTypeListViewModel>();
            vm.SelectedContractType = null;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the collection you can either set the `SelectedItem` property to null or clear the `SelectedItems`.

```
gridViewName.SelectedItem = null;
gridViewName.SelectedItems.Clear();
```

Without showing the code, we cannot precisely help you. A solution I think you can do is to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your view model and bind the selected item to a property of that type. Also check the output window if there is any binding failure.

Comment: I have updated my original message with additional information. I use MVVM Light toolkit. ObservableObject is a class from this toolkit and it implements INotifyPropertyChanged. When I set my item to `null` MVVM light crashes.